# What is a standard decimal type in Scala 2.9?

Tags: scala, decimal, bigdecimal

What is the Scala's analogue to C#'s `decimal`? Should I use java.math.BigDecimal or is there own standard type for this in Scala?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is [`scala.math.BigDecimal`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.9.x/src/library/scala/math/BigDecimal.scala) which is already imported in `Predef`. This is only a wrapper around `java.math.BigDecimal` that uses operator names for methods (like e.g. `+` instead of `add`).